# Why this query in mysql works fine with the table but not with the view of that table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, sql-order-by

Look the images, please.

The following query works great when is executed with the table '`participants`':

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        p.*, @curRow:=@curRow + 1 AS position
    FROM
        (SELECT @curRow:=0) r, 
        participants p
    WHERE
        (p.isVolunteer = 0
            OR p.isVolunteer IS NULL)
    GROUP BY p.id
    ORDER BY p.lastRegistrationDate DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 25) AS p
        INNER JOIN
    participants_registrations pr ON p.id = pr.participantId
        INNER JOIN
    registrations r ON pr.registrationId = r.id
ORDER BY p.position ASC , r.createdOn DESC
```

But, when I replace '`participants`' by the view '`vparticipants`' I cannot get the same result, that is suposed should be the same.

The problem is that the order of the results are different.

Using the table I get the rows ordered in descendant by `createdOn` column (date) and the `position` column with values starting from 1 to 25, but using the view 'vparticipants' I get the column 'position' starting from 6 to 30, and the order of column createdOn is in ascendant order. I need the same result as the table.

The view is very simple, it here:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `vparticipants` AS
    SELECT 
        `participants`.`id` AS `id`,
        `participants`.`identificationNumber` AS `identificationNumber`,
        `participants`.`firstName` AS `firstName`,
        `participants`.`lastName` AS `lastName`,
        `participants`.`email` AS `email`,
        `participants`.`cellphone` AS `cellphone`,
        `participants`.`city` AS `city`,
        `participants`.`gender` AS `gender`,
        `participants`.`shirtSize` AS `shirtSize`,
        `participants`.`bloodType` AS `bloodType`,
        `participants`.`emergencyContactName` AS `emergencyContactName`,
        `participants`.`emergencyContactPhone` AS `emergencyContactPhone`,
        `participants`.`eps` AS `eps`,
        `participants`.`birthday` AS `birthday`,
        `participants`.`memberOfGroupId` AS `memberOfGroupId`,
        `participants`.`memberOfGroupName` AS `memberOfGroupName`,
        `participants`.`lastRegistrationDate` AS `lastRegistrationDate`,
        `participants`.`isVolunteer` AS `isVolunteer`,
        `agreements_signatures`.`signatureRequest` AS `signatureRequest`,
        `agreements_signatures`.`signature` AS `signature`,
        `agreements_signatures`.`manualSignature` AS `manualSignature`,
        `agreements_signatures`.`fromWhereWasSigned` AS `fromWhereWasSigned`,
        `agreements_signatures`.`responsibleName` AS `responsibleName`,
        `agreements_signatures`.`responsibleIdentificationNumber` AS `responsibleIdentificationNumber`,
        `agreements_signatures`.`expeditionPlace` AS `expeditionPlace`,
        `agreements_signatures`.`signedIn` AS `signedIn`
    FROM
        ((`participants`
        LEFT JOIN `participants_registrations` ON ((`participants_registrations`.`participantId` = `participants`.`id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `agreements_signatures` ON ((`agreements_signatures`.`id` = `participants_registrations`.`agreementSignatureId`)))
```

Thanks any help.

RIGHT RESULTS IMAGE:
[image]

WRONG RESULTS IMAGE (VIEW):
[image]

Comment: is necessary to use the view because it offers the agreements signatures tables columns

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating functions. Typically, this will return broadly indeterminate results, but can be influenced by any indexes that might be in place. In MySQL, views have (I think) no awareness of indexes, so I suspect that might be influencing the result.

Answer (score 0):

Its because ORDER BY does not work with views, see [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/23/sql-server-order-by-does-not-work-limitation-of-the-views-part-1/) link, Its a limitation of SQL SERVER in views. It would be better to write this query without using a view

Comment: It's mysql, I removed the order by and doesn't work.

Comment: you should use direct query or put your all the logic in the view itself

Comment: in your view you have joined two more tables and surely they will also effect the result while querying on view, just remove those Left join and then try once again if the results are ok